# Scan Documents from web page or app or ext..... for free. -npapi going away issue...-

Tags: google-chrome, npapi, scanning

Currently I use a Java plugin (npapi?) that uses the morena library (http://www.gnome.sk/Morena/morena.html) to be the middle man between the local pc and it's scanner and the javascript which can talk to the server.

The user clicks a button, the javascript calls the morena scanning library and returns some encoded image data that I can then send to the server....

I hear they are turning off ALL plugins including java.

So...I need a new solution apparently.  I see a lot of posts saying buy some other software that creates plugins...to do the work (questions like: Scan documents into a Web Application)

But those won't work in a few months and I need something that will work after they shut the current solution off.  We have a website that they gather a lot of info on a web page and then scan images into attach to the info and save and I'd prefer not to rewrite the entire website as a java application.

I saw on chrome OS only a new (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/documentScan)  api...but we don't use chrome OS...yet that would be So Perfect. I think.

Currently I'm trying to make an app to use the chrome.usb or chrome.hid using the chrome dev editor but chrome.usb is undefined...therefore I can't call getDevices... :/  if that will even work for what I'm doing. :/

My final thought was to make paper boxes with a light hanging inside with a webcam and use the getUserMedia Which works!...but I'd rather let them keep the scanner beds that use auto document feeding.

**Since plugins and activeX are stepping out, is there an html5 way or chrome-app/ext way, or firefox-app way to scan documents from a web browser?**

Comment: We are not supposed to provide ideas. Post the code you tried so far to implement anything and the error you encountered.

Comment: My question is nearly identical as the question: "Scan documents into a Web Application" 

But I need a solution that will work after they turn off npapi in september of 2015 (a few months from right now).

The other guys question was answered..ish.  Did I choose the wrong website to ask quesitons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something that allows communication between a web page and a native app in Chrome, that would be [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: That seems like it's probably the best option right now.  I'll accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python Flask service, which can be called from javascript to start scanner, and get the scanned image as pdf. This python code will allow you to use image scanner from a web page. An example for a web page "client_page.html".

https://github.com/KHBillel/ImageScanner4Web